# Right Click nsbuttoncell

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I'm using Xamarin.Mac (well, I was, I'm using Visual Studio Mac now) and I'm trying to implement a right click event on a NSButtonCell (radio button).

When I do that what I'm looking to do is to strike through the text in the label for the NSButtonCell (i.e. change the font).

I cannot find out how to do this anywhere. I've tried implementing it in code in XCode instead but to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Subclass `NSButton` and override `rightMouseDown:`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Forgive my ignorance but does this involve making my own class (extending NSButtonCell) in order to override RightMouseDown? Or is there a simple way to override this one function?

Comment: Yes, this involves making your own class, a subclass of `NSButton` (without cell).